# Launch an event when scan fingerprint in Android. Is it possible?

Tags: android, launch, fingerprint, biometrics

A client ask me if is possible to launch an app when the user scan one specific finger with the fingerprint scanner in android. I think that it is possible in iOS and the TouchID, but i don't found anything related with android.

Thanks you guys!

Comment: Nowadays, it is not possible.

Comment: It depends on device used, is it on consumer device or professional specific device ?